# adding huge list to a dropdown selector in Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, sorting

I'm building an app were the user is able to select its industry type as they Sign up to the app.

In my `user.rb`model I've this code

`INDUSTRY_TYPES = [['Heavy'], ['Medium'], ['Light'], ['Dirty']]`

(These four industry types are only used for testing purposes).

and it is displayed in the `sign up` view like this:

```
  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :industry_type %>
   <%= f.select(:industry_type, options_for_select(User::INDUSTRY_TYPES)) %>
 </div>
```

Now I want to use a full list of basically all available industries instead of those four I've been using.

I found this list on github https://gist.github.com/mbejda/19012b99a12e9d014389#file-industries-csv and I want to use it instead of the four types I've been using.

So my question is basically is it possible to add that list of industry types to the array without typing them in manually?

Comment: Copy and paste?

Comment: I would rather not copy and paste about 200 words :)

Comment: I do not understand. Is coping harder the more words you copy?

Comment: I somehow thought I had to copy/paste each word separately :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy and paste the following line into your `User` model:

```
INDUSTRY_TYPES = ['Industry','Accounting','Airlines/Aviation','Alternative Dispute Resolution','Alternative Medicine','Animation','Apparel/Fashion','Architecture/Planning','Arts/Crafts','Automotive','Aviation/Aerospace','Banking/Mortgage','Biotechnology/Greentech','Broadcast Media','Building Materials','Business Supplies/Equipment','Capital Markets/Hedge Fund/Private Equity','Chemicals','Civic/Social Organization','Civil Engineering','Commercial Real Estate','Computer Games','Computer Hardware','Computer Networking','Computer Software/Engineering','Computer/Network Security','Construction','Consumer Electronics','Consumer Goods','Consumer Services','Cosmetics','Dairy','Defense/Space','Design','E-Learning','Education Management','Electrical/Electronic Manufacturing','Entertainment/Movie Production','Environmental Services','Events Services','Executive Office','Facilities Services','Farming','Financial Services','Fine Art','Fishery','Food Production','Food/Beverages','Fundraising','Furniture','Gambling/Casinos','Glass/Ceramics/Concrete','Government Administration','Government Relations','Graphic Design/Web Design','Health/Fitness','Higher Education/Acadamia','Hospital/Health Care','Hospitality','Human Resources/HR','Import/Export','Individual/Family Services','Industrial Automation','Information Services','Information Technology/IT','Insurance','International Affairs','International Trade/Development','Internet','Investment Banking/Venture','Investment Management/Hedge Fund/Private Equity','Judiciary','Law Enforcement','Law Practice/Law Firms','Legal Services','Legislative Office','Leisure/Travel','Library','Logistics/Procurement','Luxury Goods/Jewelry','Machinery','Management Consulting','Maritime','Market Research','Marketing/Advertising/Sales','Mechanical or Industrial Engineering','Media Production','Medical Equipment','Medical Practice','Mental Health Care','Military Industry','Mining/Metals','Motion Pictures/Film','Museums/Institutions','Music','Nanotechnology','Newspapers/Journalism','Non-Profit/Volunteering','Oil/Energy/Solar/Greentech','Online Publishing','Other Industry','Outsourcing/Offshoring','Package/Freight Delivery','Packaging/Containers','Paper/Forest Products','Performing Arts','Pharmaceuticals','Philanthropy','Photography','Plastics','Political Organization','Primary/Secondary Education','Printing','Professional Training','Program Development','Public Relations/PR','Public Safety','Publishing Industry','Railroad Manufacture','Ranching','Real Estate/Mortgage','Recreational Facilities/Services','Religious Institutions','Renewables/Environment','Research Industry','Restaurants','Retail Industry','Security/Investigations','Semiconductors','Shipbuilding','Sporting Goods','Sports','Staffing/Recruiting','Supermarkets','Telecommunications','Textiles','Think Tanks','Tobacco','Translation/Localization','Transportation','Utilities','Venture Capital/VC','Veterinary','Warehousing','Wholesale','Wine/Spirits','Wireless','Writing/Editing']
```

Another option might be to copy that list into an external file (CSV or YAML) and load it into the `INDUSTRY_TYPES` constant.

Just save the following into `config/industry_types.yml`:

```
---
- Industry
- Accounting
- Airlines/Aviation
- Alternative Dispute Resolution
- Alternative Medicine
- Animation
- Apparel/Fashion
- Architecture/Planning
- Arts/Crafts
- Automotive
- Aviation/Aerospace
- Banking/Mortgage
- Biotechnology/Greentech
- Broadcast Media
- Building Materials
- Business Supplies/Equipment
- Capital Markets/Hedge Fund/Private Equity
- Chemicals
- Civic/Social Organization
- Civil Engineering
- Commercial Real Estate
- Computer Games
- Computer Hardware
- Computer Networking
- Computer Software/Engineering
- Computer/Network Security
- Construction
- Consumer Electronics
- Consumer Goods
- Consumer Services
- Cosmetics
- Dairy
- Defense/Space
- Design
- E-Learning
- Education Management
- Electrical/Electronic Manufacturing
- Entertainment/Movie Production
- Environmental Services
- Events Services
- Executive Office
- Facilities Services
- Farming
- Financial Services
- Fine Art
- Fishery
- Food Production
- Food/Beverages
- Fundraising
- Furniture
- Gambling/Casinos
- Glass/Ceramics/Concrete
- Government Administration
- Government Relations
- Graphic Design/Web Design
- Health/Fitness
- Higher Education/Acadamia
- Hospital/Health Care
- Hospitality
- Human Resources/HR
- Import/Export
- Individual/Family Services
- Industrial Automation
- Information Services
- Information Technology/IT
- Insurance
- International Affairs
- International Trade/Development
- Internet
- Investment Banking/Venture
- Investment Management/Hedge Fund/Private Equity
- Judiciary
- Law Enforcement
- Law Practice/Law Firms
- Legal Services
- Legislative Office
- Leisure/Travel
- Library
- Logistics/Procurement
- Luxury Goods/Jewelry
- Machinery
- Management Consulting
- Maritime
- Market Research
- Marketing/Advertising/Sales
- Mechanical or Industrial Engineering
- Media Production
- Medical Equipment
- Medical Practice
- Mental Health Care
- Military Industry
- Mining/Metals
- Motion Pictures/Film
- Museums/Institutions
- Music
- Nanotechnology
- Newspapers/Journalism
- Non-Profit/Volunteering
- Oil/Energy/Solar/Greentech
- Online Publishing
- Other Industry
- Outsourcing/Offshoring
- Package/Freight Delivery
- Packaging/Containers
- Paper/Forest Products
- Performing Arts
- Pharmaceuticals
- Philanthropy
- Photography
- Plastics
- Political Organization
- Primary/Secondary Education
- Printing
- Professional Training
- Program Development
- Public Relations/PR
- Public Safety
- Publishing Industry
- Railroad Manufacture
- Ranching
- Real Estate/Mortgage
- Recreational Facilities/Services
- Religious Institutions
- Renewables/Environment
- Research Industry
- Restaurants
- Retail Industry
- Security/Investigations
- Semiconductors
- Shipbuilding
- Sporting Goods
- Sports
- Staffing/Recruiting
- Supermarkets
- Telecommunications
- Textiles
- Think Tanks
- Tobacco
- Translation/Localization
- Transportation
- Utilities
- Venture Capital/VC
- Veterinary
- Warehousing
- Wholesale
- Wine/Spirits
- Wireless
- Writing/Editing
```

And load that file in your model like this:

```
INDUSTRY_TYPES = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join('config', 'industry_types.yml')).freeze
```

Comment: thank you @spickermann, this will work for now, but I was thinking more about loading it to the constant, but I'm not sure how to do that. It would be nice if you could provide an example how to do that?

Comment: @DaudiHell Please see my updated answer for an example how to keep that list in an external file.

Comment: You can also use [`Rails.application.config_for(:industry_types)`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/Application.html#method-i-config_for) since it's in `config/` just need to key it under `production:` and then you can add in `development:` and `test:` to have separate values for each environment